# when I try to upload images koa2 ctx.req.files = [] but ctx.request.files have the files I upload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, koa2

font code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input ref="file" type="file">
    <button @click="save">保存</button>
  </div>
</template>

save() {
  const formData = new FormData()
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
  formData.append('name', this.name)
  formData.append('img', this.$refs.file.files[0])
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin/timeline/addImg', formData, headers)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
       })
    })
}
```

back-end code

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './static/')
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    const name = file.originalname
    const extension = name.substring(name.length - 4)
    cb(null, 'img-' + Date.now() + extension)
  }
})

const upload = multer({storage: storage})

router.post('/addImg', upload.array('img', 5), async(ctx) => {
  const files = ctx.request.files; // has files
  const files = ctx.request.files; // []
  console.log('files', files)
  ctx.body = { msg: '添加成功' }
})
```

console.log(ctx.request.files):

[image: console.log(ctx.request.files)]

request headers:

[image: request headers]

so files still can not save to '/static'. I don`t konw where is the problem, I need your help.
thank you very much

Comment: In the code you posted, it seems like you have the same exact line twice but you say it gives different results? Though I don't know if I understand the question, why can't you just use `ctx.request.files` if it gives you what you want?

Comment: it`s true that ctx.request.files and ctx.req.files get different results. It`s like the koa-multer using ctx.req.files to handle file type. when I use the 'fs' of node, I can get what I want. so maybe the false appears the using of koa-multer